# Incrementing a counter based on a partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, partitioning

Suppose I have a table that looks a little like this in SQL Server 2008:

```
UID    Std_RecordID
-------------------
1      10
2      10
3      12
4      10
5      10
6      10
7      12
```

Basically there will be a sequence of `10`s followed by a single `12`. The `10` could also be in the list `14, 50, 21, 24, 31` and the `12` could be in the list `16, 52, 23, 26, 33` respectively. An increment of 2 pretty much signifies the end of a set.

I need to increment a counter every time there is a new set.

I know I can get a counter to increment and reset like so:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Std_RecordId order by UID) 'Ind'
,UID
from @inputTable
```

But this isn't quite what I want given that it will produce the following:

```
UID    Std_RecordId    Ind
---------------------------
1      10              1
2      10              2
3      12              1
4      10              1
5      10              2
6      10              3
7      12              1
```

I need it to do something like this instead:

```
UID    Std_RecordId    Ind
------------------------------
1      10              1
2      10              1
3      12              1
4      10              2
5      10              2
6      10              2
7      12              2
```

How does one go about accomplishing this without resorting to iteration? I'm trying to get rid of the iteration in the procedure I'm working in since the iteration is the slowest part of the procedure (it does loads of other things other than this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your problem to "How many times has a record with a value of 12 appeared before the current record", then add one to the result. To get the count of records you can use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
DECLARE @InputTable TABLE (UID INT, Std_RecordId INT);
INSERT @InputTable (UID, Std_RecordId)
VALUES (1, 10), (2, 10), (3, 12), (4, 10), (5, 10), (6, 10), (7, 12);

SELECT  i.UID,
        i.Std_RecordId,
        t.Ind
FROM    @InputTable AS i
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  Ind = COUNT(*) + 1
            FROM    @InputTable AS t
            WHERE   t.Std_RecordId = 12
            AND     t.UID < i.UID
        ) AS t;
```

---

**EDIT**

Just to elaborate on what I said in a comment about a temp table rather than a table variable, the exact same query with the exact same data consistently runs significantly faster in my tests:

The script I ran was:

```
DECLARE @InputTable TABLE (UID INT, Std_RecordId INT);

INSERT @InputTable (UID, Std_RecordId)
SELECT  TOP 50000
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id),
        CEILING(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 20)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;

CREATE TABLE #InputTable (UID INT, Std_RecordId INT);
INSERT #InputTable (UID, Std_RecordId)
SELECT  UID, Std_RecordId
FROM    @InputTable;

SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

SELECT  i.UID,
        i.Std_RecordId,
        t.Ind
FROM    @InputTable AS i
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  Ind = COUNT(*) + 1
            FROM    @InputTable AS t
            WHERE   t.Std_RecordId = 12
            AND     t.UID < i.UID
        ) AS t;

SELECT  i.UID,
        i.Std_RecordId,
        t.Ind
FROM    #InputTable AS i
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  Ind = COUNT(*) + 1
            FROM    #InputTable AS t
            WHERE   t.Std_RecordId = 12
            AND     t.UID < i.UID
        ) AS t;

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;

DROP TABLE #InputTable;
```

As I increased the sample size the gap got bigger, but for 10,000 rows (I got bored of waiting with any more) the table variable consistently took about 7.9 seconds, whereas the temp table was averaging 0.4. I ran this once for 50,000 rows, and the table variable took 190 seconds, the temp table took 4.6, so a huge difference.

The other advantadge is that your temp table can be indexed, however the best performance I found with a temp table, was to create a new temp table to record the positions of your markers, then use this to give your original table a rank:

```
DECLARE @InputTable TABLE (UID INT, Std_RecordId INT);

INSERT @InputTable (UID, Std_RecordId)
SELECT  TOP 1000000
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id),
        CEILING(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 20)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;

DECLARE @Counter TABLE (UID INT PRIMARY KEY, Ind INT NOT NULL);
INSERT @Counter
SELECT  UID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UID) + 1
FROM    @InputTable
WHERE   Std_RecordId = 12;

SELECT  i.UID,
        i.Std_RecordId,
        Ind = ISNULL(t.Ind, 1)
FROM    @InputTable AS i
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Ind
            FROM    @Counter AS t
            WHERE   t.UID < i.UID
        ) AS t
ORDER BY i.UID;
```

For 50,000 rows this consistently ran in less than a second, even for a million it was running in 15-20 seconds.

Comment: I'm assuming I can replace `t.Std_RecordId = 12` with my list of terminators, correct? If so, you rock and I thank you kind sir!

Comment: When I get my procedure working I'll be able to test it and mark it correct. :)

Comment: I tested it and it seems to work, but it's quite slow. It takes 10m30s to get through 42k records, which isn't much at all :(

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table?

Comment: UID and a couple other columns, but I don't have any indexes on my table variable. I did try running the query against the original source table that has an index, which gave me the time of 10m30s. On the table variable I got around 13 minutes. The problem with the approach you've taken is that it takes longer the more records it has, as it has to count each and every single record every time it does the check. But I can't think of any other way of doing it.

Comment: Do you have to use a table variable, there are two problems with table variables, the first is that you cannot index them, the second is that the statistics are very rarely updated, so the execution plan is usually based on an estimated 1 row, so this is not going to be optimal for a large number of rows. Could you use a local temporary table instead?

Comment: Well the procedure I'm rewriting uses the table variable as an input, so I'd like to keep compatibility. However I can fetch data from actual tables using the data from the table variable, since the table variable is simply a copy of the data in the actual table. Like I said before though, there was a 3 minute difference between the table variable and the actual table in my testing. I also had to change it slightly to do comparisons for position on a different column and not the UID column, which has slowed things down even more.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your updated one is perfect and nice and fast. :)